# Which one is preffered in a WHERE clause: 'wild cards' or 'String Functions'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, wildcard

I know that both Wild Cards and Functions must be avoided in the WHERE clauses if possible. My question is: which one is yet better in terms of performance, assuming that we have to choose between one of them? More specifically, I have the following two queries and I want to know which type of query is preferred in general:

```
select FirstName from person.person where FirstName like 'S%'

select FirstName from person.person where LEFT(FirstName,1) = 'S'
```

PS. I have checked the execution time of both queries and there was no noticeable difference in this specific case. Here are the execution plans:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the code for the index *IX_Person_LastName_FirstName_MiddleName*  is defined:

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_Person_LastName_FirstName_MiddleName]       Script Date: 11/30/2016 12:53:05 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Person_LastName_FirstName_MiddleName] ON [Person].[Person]
(
[LastName] ASC,
[FirstName] ASC,
[MiddleName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO;
```

Here is a few links I found about this issue, though they do not completely answer my question:

[AvoidFunctionsInWereClause_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178270/getting-rid-of-functions-in-the-where-clause)

[AvoidFunctionsInWereClause_2](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/12/sql-server-avoid-using-function-in-where-clause-scan-to-seek/)

[AvoidLikeClause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543580/equals-vs-like)

Comment: You should show us how you create the index.

Comment: Wildcards are usually only an issue if you start the string with them (or the character sequence preceding them start the majority of the compared field's values); most function use ends up with table scans unless the RDBMS has special optimizations for those functions.

Comment: How many rows are there? `LIKE 'S%'` will use an index (while `LIKE '%s'`) won't. I'd think, that the engine is smart enough to handle `LEFT` similarly...

Comment: @Uueerdo So, do you mean in this case using LIKE is prefered since it doesn't start with the wild cards?

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza I didn't create the indexes. Its AdventureWorks2012. I'll add a picture of all the indexes on the table.

Comment: @TheEsisia yes, in this case, and assuming the field is indexed; if the field isn't indexed it really doesn't matter either way. (Edit: Also, I am not sure how much the wildcard adage applies to MSSQL; though I am familiar with MSSQL, most my experience is in MySQL.)

Comment: In this case you need to show how `IX_Person_LastName_FirstName_MiddleName` is defined

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza I'm adding the code for that index into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both queries are doing index scan so those are OK. But we dont know how you setup your index or table sizes.

First version can use a basic index on firstName because the `%` is at the end.

```
 FirstName like 'S%'

 FirstName Like '%S%' -- cant use index
```

Second Version **cant** use the index on firstName, but you can create a calculated index for `LEFT(FirstName,1)` that is why you should show us your index.

This is article have the best tips to create index.  MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)